# Play Radio Stream - shoutcast v2 - MediaPlayer and PrepareAsync - not working

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'm trying to write a player, that will play the audio stream - shoutcast v2 (I tried all formats to play a stream - .pls, .m3u, .mp3 and clean http://example.com:port).

The following code running in the emulator, works for phone ZTE (Android 4.1.2) but it does not work, eg. A Sony Xperia M (Android 4.3) and did not know why.

The code has already been written in various ways and still have not solved the problem.

P.S. One app from the Play Store also does not work, play (MaxItalo Player) but another (eg. RadioParty) reproduces the stream.

My code (part of the code):

```
private class PlayM extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {       
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.show();
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(url));
                mPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                errorToast.setText("IllegalArgumentException "+e1);
                errorToast.show();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e2) {
                errorToast.setText("IllegalStateException "+e2);
                errorToast.show();
            } catch (IOException e3) {
                errorToast.setText("IOException "+e3);
                errorToast.show();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
                    dialog.hide();
                    player.start();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public void clickPlay(View v) {
        if(mPlayer==null) {
            new PlayM().execute();
        }
    }
```